# Merge 2 videos side by side duet video with swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, video

Please help me to merge 2 separate mp4 videos side by side as like duet video feature of musically (TikTok) app with swift for iOS app like below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve this by using two UIVIEW,and assign  each one to swift class like this.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

    class videoplaying: UIView {
        override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
            return AVPlayerLayer.self;
        }
        var playerlayer: AVPlayerLayer{
            return layer as! AVPlayerLayer;
        }
        var player: AVPlayer?{
            get{
                return playerlayer.player
            }
            set {
                playerlayer.player = newValue
            }
        }
        var playetitem: AVPlayerItem?


    }
```

Comment: I actually want to merge 2 videos because I also needs share feature. Separate video playing at once will not fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Hello @Touhid, I am facing same issue have you got any solution for merging it as a two parallel video. Please guide if you got the solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
  let commandValue = "-y -i \(self.videoFilePath1) -i \(self.videoFilePath2) -filter_complex nullsrc=size=\(value4*2)*\(value3)[base];[\(0):v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=\(value4)*\(value3)[upperleft];[\(1):v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=\(value4)*\(value3)[upperright];[base][upperleft]overlay=shortest=\(1):x=\(0):y=\(0)[tmp1];[tmp1][upperright]overlay=shortest=\(1):x=\(value4):y=\(0) -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -strict experimental -preset ultrafast -t \(self.sendDuration) \(destination)"
MobileFFmpeg.execute(commandValue)
```